# Logs: log4j or lucene?

Tags: java, lucene, log4j, logging

We are building a web app, and my boss insists on using lucene, because the logs will be indexed and the admin can search and query it after.

But, IMHO, lucene is an indexing API, so, I think that the correct is use it to index things, not to store logs. The admin usually is a admin, not a dumb user. He could perfectly open the log files and search inside it with a CTRL+F like shortcut.

log4j is an log API, so, it means that it should be used to log things. I think that it is the correct choice.

Am I right? What do you think about it?
Exists a API that could be used to query a log file?

thanks.

Comment: You wouldn't log with lucene. You'd log with a logger. You could index log files *later*, but I'm not convinced lucerne would add a lot of value unless your logs contain a lot of prose. DB logging, or post-processing, would likely be a better option.

Comment: but, then the database will not slow down?

Comment: If you log to a DB, sure, there will be the overhead of DB logging, just like anything else that writes to a DB. I have no way of knowing if your app/infrastructure can support it or not. The DB portion can also be loaded from log files, or handled as a separate task from the existing files, or... etc.

Comment: it was what I was thinking. Thanks.

Comment: You would use *both* solutions, use a logging framework to *log*, and then if you want to search the logs, index the *logs* and search them with Lucene.  Think of it like a processing pipeline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Lucene Homepage](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) states: "Apache Lucene(TM) is a high-performance, full-featured text search engine library written entirely in Java. It is a technology suitable for nearly any application that requires full-text search, especially cross-platform. "

It is definitely not a logging framework and I wont recommed it for this issue. Use [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/) for logging or distributed loggig with [Syslog4j](http://syslog4j.org/).

Answer (score 6):

I also agree that one should use log4j, generates log files and search using the ctrl + f, Lucene is not a good choice for this situation

Answer (score 2):

Lucene is a text search engine API, not a logging framework. I would prefer [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/). You could use a DB appender and then query your results as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Log4j has a JDBC appender. This obviously would not update the index. If it is ok to update the index manually or scheduled, i.e. not having real time capability, then this is a quite easy setup. If this is not acceptable you could write a custom appender that uses Lucene or Hibernate Search. So it is possible and depending on the amount of search needed within the logs it may even be useful.

But: You add additional logging overhead and possible problems (database and index problems) with this approach. If searching through logfiles is a task so common that the log files have to be indexed something else smells.

Answer (score 2):

Your boss is probably looking for something like [splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) (centralized indexing and a nice query interface).

Disclaimer: it'sa comercial product and I don't work for them nor am I associated in any way with the product :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the use case would be the same lucene to facilitate the search and query. In an application that has several different logs, for example, login logs, logs of actions for an module, logs of the action in another module, logs privileged actions.

And the query would be possible for users with permission within the system in the form of reports, so they can inspect the occurrences.

Still do not know Splunk, might solve this problem